# NLP NER Processing Errors

Tags: stanford-nlp

here is the tsv file. c2is2r3.tsv

```
The O
fate    O
of  O
Lehman  ORGANIZATION
Brothers    ORGANIZATION

. . .

New ORGANIZATION
York    ORGANIZATION
Fed ORGANIZATION
,   O
and O
Treasury    TITLE
Secretary   TITLE
Henry   PERSON
M.  PERSON
Paulson PERSON
Jr. PERSON
.   O
```

more c2is2r3.prop

```
trainFile = c2is2r3.tsv
serializeTo = c2is2r3-ner-model.ser.gz
map = word=0,answer=1

useClassFeature=true
useWord=true
useNGrams=true
noMidNGrams=true
maxNGramLeng=6
usePrev=true
useNext=true
useSequences=true
usePrevSequences=true
maxLeft=1
useTypeSeqs=true
useTypeSeqs2=true
useTypeySequences=true
wordShape=chris2useLC
useDisjunctive=true
```

Here is the original sequence

```
java -cp  stanford-ner-3.5.2.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop c2is2r3.prop


java -cp stanford-ner-3.5.2.jar -mx2g edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner -ner.model c2is2r3-ner-model.ser.gz,classifiers/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz -ner.useSUTime false -ner.combinationMode HIGH_RECALL -serializeTo c2is2.serialized.ncc.ncc.ser.gz


java -cp stanford-ner-3.5.2.jar -mx1g edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -loadClassifier c2is2.serialized.ncc.ncc.ser.gz -textFile c2is2r3.txt


CRFClassifier invoked on Fri Jul 17 09:51:13 EDT 2015 with arguments:
   -loadClassifier c2is2.serialized.ncc.ncc.ser.gz -textFile c2is2r3.txt
loadClassifier=c2is2.serialized.ncc.ncc.ser.gz
textFile=c2is2r3.txt
Loading classifier from /mnt/hgfs/share/nlp/stanford-ner-2015-04-20/c2is2.serialized.ncc.ncc.ser.gz ... Error deserializing /mnt/hgfs/share/nlp/stanford-ner-2015-04-20/c2is2.serialized.ncc.ncc.ser.gz
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Properties cannot be cast to [Ledu.stanford.nlp.util.Index;
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifierNoExceptions(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1572)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifierNoExceptions(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1523)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.main(CRFClassifier.java:2987)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Properties cannot be cast to [Ledu.stanford.nlp.util.Index;
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.loadClassifier(CRFClassifier.java:2613)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1451)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1558)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifierNoExceptions(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1569)
    ... 2 more
```

This is an attempt to use the **NERClassifierCombiner**

```
java -cp stanford-ner-3.5.2.jar -mx1g edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner  -loadClassifier c2is2.serialized.ncc.ncc.ser.gz -testFile c2is2r3.txt
```

This is the error stack:

```
NERClassifierCombiner invoked on Fri Jul 17 10:11:17 EDT 2015 with arguments:
   -loadClassifier c2is2.serialized.ncc.ncc.ser.gz -testFile c2is2r3.txt
testFile=c2is2r3.txt
loadClassifier=c2is2.serialized.ncc.ncc.ser.gz
testFile=c2is2r3.txt
ner.useSUTime=false
ner.model=c2is2r3-ner-model.ser.gz,classifiers/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz
serializeTo=c2is2.serialized.ncc.ncc.ser.gz
loadClassifier=c2is2.serialized.ncc.ncc.ser.gz
ner.combinationMode=HIGH_RECALL
loading CRF...
loading CRF...
Error on line 1: The fate of Lehman Brothers, the beleaguered investment bank, hung in the balance on Sunday as Federal Reserve officials and the leaders of major financial institutions continued to gather in emergency meetings trying to complete a plan to rescue the stricken bank.  Several possible plans emerged from the talks, held at the Federal Reserve Bank of New York and led by Timothy R. Geithner, the president of the New York Fed, and Treasury Secretary Henry M. Paulson Jr.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Argument array lengths differ: [word, tag, answer] vs. [The, fate, of, Lehman, Brothers,, the, beleaguered, investment, bank,, hung, in, the, balance, on, Sunday, as, Federal, Reserve, officials, and, the, leaders, of, major, financial, institutions, continued, to, gather, in, emergency, meetings, trying, to, complete, a, plan, to, rescue, the, stricken, bank., Several, possible, plans, emerged, from, the, talks,, held, at, the, Federal, Reserve, Bank, of, New, York, and, led, by, Timothy, R., Geithner,, the, president, of, the, New, York, Fed,, and, Treasury, Secretary, Henry, M., Paulson, Jr.]
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel.initFromStrings(CoreLabel.java:153)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel.<init>(CoreLabel.java:133)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.ColumnDocumentReaderAndWriter$ColumnDocParser.apply(ColumnDocumentReaderAndWriter.java:85)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.ColumnDocumentReaderAndWriter$ColumnDocParser.apply(ColumnDocumentReaderAndWriter.java:60)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.DelimitRegExIterator.parseString(DelimitRegExIterator.java:67)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.DelimitRegExIterator.setNext(DelimitRegExIterator.java:60)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.DelimitRegExIterator.<init>(DelimitRegExIterator.java:54)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.DelimitRegExIterator$DelimitRegExIteratorFactory.getIterator(DelimitRegExIterator.java:122)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.ColumnDocumentReaderAndWriter.getIterator(ColumnDocumentReaderAndWriter.java:54)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ObjectBank$OBIterator.setNextObject(ObjectBank.java:436)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ObjectBank$OBIterator.<init>(ObjectBank.java:415)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ObjectBank.iterator(ObjectBank.java:253)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.ObjectBankWrapper.iterator(ObjectBankWrapper.java:52)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.classifyAndWriteAnswers(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1160)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.classifyAndWriteAnswers(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1111)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.classifyAndWriteAnswers(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1071)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner.main(NERClassifierCombiner.java:382)
```

So not sure what to do next.  Any other combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the serialize step you are serializing with:

edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner

During the load step you are loading with:

edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier

So in the second command, use edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner instead and the error should go away.  You serialized an NERClassifierCombiner, but are trying to load it as a CRFClassifier.  Please let me know if you have any other troubles!

Comment: Please review updated section above. I hope this helps.

Comment: Add "-map word=0,answer=1" to your command, that should fix that issue

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd file c2is2r3.txt needs to be converted into a tsv file first and then it needs to be passed into your command.

You can just associate O (if you are not sure or want to save time manually tagging it) to all the tokens generated and then test with your model.